# makecert.exe generate certificates but (certificates)its does not show in certmgr windows?

Tags: ssl, wcf-security, claims-based-identity

C:\windows\system32\makecert.exe -r -n "CN=HanuSoft CA" -pe -sv HanuSoftCA.pvk -a sha1 -len 2048 -b 09/04/2013 -e 09/05/2016 -cy authority HanuSoft.cer

after taking password..

Succeed

but m not found any certificate in certmgr windows,
please any one help to resolve this problem why its not generate or other prob with it.

Comment: You can Check in InternetExplorer.IE->Internet Options->Content->Certificates. Follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140234(v=office.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Both private key and public key were stored in the .pvk file, not immediately import into the keystore.

Comment: but m not find .pvk file where is it in my local system, and makecert command will successfull executed